# How to get the start date and end date of every week in current month using mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I want the result to be like this:-

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| Week Number |   start date  |    end date    |
|----------------------------------------------|
|      1      |   2018-02-01  |    2018-02-04  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|      2      |   2018-02-05  |    2018-02-11  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|      3      |   2018-02-12  |    2018-02-18  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|      4      |   2018-02-19  |    2018-02-25  |
|----------------------------------------------|
|      5      |   2018-02-26  |    2018-02-28  |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Since, the first day of February 2018 was on Thursday, the first week is from 1 to 4 (the immediate Sunday).

I have a query, which gives me the start date and end date of all the weeks till now.

```
$currentWeekData = $this->CustomerPayment->query('SELECT WEEK(CURDATE()) AS current_week');
$currentWeek = $currentWeekData[0][0]['current_week'];
for($w = 0; $w <= $currentWeek; $w++)
{
    $flagPay = 0;
    $flagDep = 0;
    $actualWeek = intval($w + 1);
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $currentYearFirstDay = $currentYear.'-01-01';
    $queryWeekRange = "SELECT '$currentYearFirstDay'+INTERVAL ($actualWeek-WEEK('$currentYearFirstDay', 1))*7 - WEEKDAY('$currentYearFirstDay') DAY as start_date,'$currentYearFirstDay'+INTERVAL ($actualWeek-WEEK('$currentYearFirstDay', 1)+1)*7-1 - WEEKDAY('$currentYearFirstDay') DAY as end_date";
    $resultWeekRange = $this->CustomerPayment->query($queryWeekRange);
}
```

But I want the query to list the weekly range of the current month only. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need a database for this? Would this be better done in PHP? [PHP has an extensive selection of date & time functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @schwern, do you really need to do this in a database? This would be much more efficient in PHP. Except a few more lines indeed (but I doubt that one rather simple MySQL query actually can achieve what you are asking).

I would have done something like this in PHP (but I would not promise that this is the most efficient way).

```
$currentMonth = 12; //Could be date("n") or 1-12
$currentYear = date('Y'); //Could also be any year
$firstDate = strtotime("$currentYear-$currentMonth-1");
$lastDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-t', $firstDate));
$isLastDayPassed = false;
$loopingDate = $firstDate;
$weeks = [];
$weekNumber = 1;
while(!$isLastDayPassed){
    if(date("n", $loopingDate) != $currentMonth){
        $isLastDayPassed = true;
        continue;
    }
    $firstDayOfWeek = date('w', $loopingDate) == 1 ? date('Y-m-d', $loopingDate) : date('Y-m-d', $loopingDate);
    $lastDayOfWeek = date("n", strtotime("next sunday", $loopingDate)) == $currentMonth ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next sunday", $loopingDate)) : date('Y-m-d', $lastDate);

    $weeks[] = [
        "start_date" => $firstDayOfWeek,
        "end_date" => $lastDayOfWeek,
        "week_number" => $weekNumber
    ];
    $loopingDate = strtotime("next monday", $loopingDate);
    $weekNumber++;
}
```